# Approval Process deployment failing with strange error

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, deployment-error

I am deploying a Approval Process file via Metadata API and it is erroring out stating:

The approval process contains an invalid submitter value abc@validusername.com for type user.

The abc@validusername.com is a valid and active username and I have included that under the allowedSubmitters element with a type 'User' as below:

```
    <allowedSubmitters>
        <submitter>abc@validusername.com</submitter>
        <type>user</type>
    </allowedSubmitters>
```

But event when it is valid, the deployment fails with the stated error.

Any suggestions to resolve this? I want to deploy this file as a metadata itself rather than manually edit the component in Production.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of things, I deployed the component by commenting out the allowedSubmitters node and fixing it in Production. Nothing else seemed to work.